# How to set API path in vue.config.js for production?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-cli

I'm using vue cli3 for setup. I already have devServer api set up as such in `vue.config.js` file:

```
devServer: {
    proxy: {
        '/api': {
            target: 'http://localhost:1888/apps/test/mainapp.php/',
            changeOrigin: true,
        },
    },
}
```

I also need to set path 'https://server/myapp/main.php/' as the production API path, but I can't seem to find any info in the [documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/) on how to do it. Any help is appreciated.

Brief example of what i'm doing in code:

```
methods: {
    login() {
        this.axios.post('/api/test')
            .then((resp) => {
                console.log(resp);
            })
            .catch(() => {
                console.log('err:' , err);
            });
    },
},
```

Comment: there's no `config` directory with the new setup (cli3)

Comment: if so, one solution will be set up redirect rule at your `production` **front end** server (apache/iis etc), then all requests to `https://frontend-server\api` will be redirected to `https://backend-server/myapp/main.php/`, then remember to add CORS rules.

Comment: @Sphinx that's what i do now, but i was wondering if there's a way to exclude the server out of the equation

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your `devServer` does not run when you execute `yarn/npm run build`. You are only being supplied with the transpiled javascript to be served. You'll need to change your URL in your .env files.

Development:

```
.env

VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT = '/api'
```

Production:

```
.env.production

VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT ='https://server/myapp/main.php'
```

Then your XHR Request library should be using these environment variables when making requests, such as with axios:

```
axios[method](process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT, data)
```

Where `method` would be `GET/POST/PUT/DELETE`.

Do note that you will be restricted to the rules put in place by Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing. If your server is not allowing the URL serving your Vue.js pages, you'll need to open it up.

You don't need to make any changes to your `devServer` configuration because your `.env` will now declare xhr requests sent to `/api` which will still proxy for you.

Comment: where do i find the `.env` files?

Comment: @andrei You make these yourself in the root of your project. Please have [a read over the documentation on environment variables](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html), as there's a ton of useful information here, especially concerning the `modes` idea.

Comment: From what I understand, those files are only loaded when used with vue-cli-service, but i'm only using `yarn serve` and `yarn build` commands, and they don't appear to be looking at the .env files

Comment: @andrei They absolutely due. The `.env` files are loaded depending on your environment. Change `.env`. to `.env.development` for instance. Add variables and log them out to watch them change. The `vue-cli-service` is called under the hood when you run `yarn serve` and `yarn build`, they natively call `vue-cli-service serve` which calls the `serve` library. In fact, you can pass a directory to server as well to have your `serve` run your production files, such as with `yarn serve --dist` to serve from your `dist` directory.

Comment: I see that now. But I'm trying to keep the code clean, so I want to be able to simply put `/api/method` in the url instead of prefixing every call with `process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT`. How can I accomplish that? I updated my question with the code example.

Comment: @andrei Ah. I see, the real problem is that you're using `this.axios`... everywhere. That should be an `AxiosInstance` that is globally configured with `Axios.create({ baseUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_API_ENDPOINT })`. Then you reference that. No need to pass the base url each time.

Comment: I set up using your suggestion, but now it's giving me the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error, it wasn't giving that error with the devServer settings for some reason. (i didn't change the php code)

Comment: Yes, you're going to have that error (in production) because a client cannot directly send a request to a server that has a different domain name. The server needs to be configured to allow Cross Origin Resource Sharing for that domain.

Comment: what's odd is that it works fine when i set the `devServer` options in `vue.config.js` file. any idea why?

Comment: @andrei In the production environment that works for you? It should not. Can we see your `package.json` block for `scripts`?

Comment: `  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },` it does not work in production

Comment: after some tinkering, i got it to work using your suggestion. added a plugin for axios with config specifying the baseURL

Comment: to be noted: `VUE_APP_` prefix is [required](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables) (When I had a variable named `VUE_DEV_API_ENDPOINT` it didn't work - `process.env.VUE_DEV_API_ENDPOINT` was undefined)

Answer (score 4):

You are using `axios` in your code, so you can try:

```
// service.js
import axios from 'axios';
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://server/myapp/main.php/';
export default axios;

// main.js
Vue.prototype.$axios = axios;

// In your component
login() {
    this.$axios.post('/api/test', data)
        .then((resp) => {
            console.log(resp);
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log('err:' , err);
        });
}
```

Then every request would send with the default `baseUrl` you set.

Check out more options for [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios%22options%22)

Answer (score 0):

If your vue-cli version is higher than 3.x, then add your

> **development** variables in **.env** file
>
> **production** variables in **.env.production** file

Only variables that start with **VUE_APP_** will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin. You can access them in your application code: console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET) [Vue Doc](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code)